# Servlet jdbc path

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, maven, workbench

I have created a database using MySql workbench and i need to configure the database path on my servlet. What is the correct way to write the path?

I have tried

```
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/testone" />
```

but i get an error saying could not connect to jdbc database. On MySql Workbench I have Host: localhost Port: 3306. and when I run my project, the url is http://localhost:8080/ when i click "submit", which is supposed to send the data to database it gives

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

Comment: Do not use JDBC directly in a servlet. Learn about 3tier architecture

Answer (score 0):

MySql Workbench runs in 3306 Port, which is the default. Your application runs in 8080 port. Try

```
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testone" />
```